# faces.length is always 0 in FaceDetectionListener

Tags: android, face-detection

Attempting to use Android 4 API 14 face recognition

Testing code on Samsung SII 4.0 
Face Detection Listener is registered

```
mCamera.setFaceDetectionListener(new MyFaceDetectionListener());
```

It supports Face Recognition as

```
if (params.getMaxNumDetectedFaces() > 0)
```

returns 35

Facing problem in FaceDetectionListener's onFaceDetection method

```
public void onFaceDetection(Face[] faces, Camera camera) 
{

    }
```

Here length of faces[] is always 0 i.e. no face is detected . 
I am confused no face is detected then why **onFaceDetection()** is getting called.
Please help

Comment: accept answer to some of your questions. If answer to a question is correct, use thick button to the left of it. Do it at all your questions.

Comment: @ slezadav Ok Please help me I am not able to detect a face .

Comment: @MahajanGuy did you figure this out?

Comment: I have faced similar situation. Wise thing to do would be to proceed with a check on faces.length